# php yii framework extension for page management

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Could you please advise me some yii framework extension for page management.

I'd like to have possibility to create/edit common pages like "terms of use" and "privacy policy" in administration panel with  WYSIWYG editor.

How to create such kind of functionality in Yii ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To admin panel with the best WYSIWYG editor extensions are:

- [CLEditor](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cleditor/)
- [Yii RedactorJS WYSIWYG](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-redactorjs-wysiwyg-widget/)

Comment: Thanks ! RedactorJS is really awesome !

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=wysiwyg) are a lot of extensions for different editors. Review them and pick any you like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but WYSIWYG is only a part of the requested functionality. In my case - I need to implement all process in order to create page, choose site url for this page, edit page content in WYSIWYG. Maybe some Yii extension exist for this purpose ?

Comment: Ah, understood. Sorry, I didn't see such kind of extensions. It's a pretty easy task. Just need to make a form with say title and body, and write the page to page view file on create/update and delete the file on delete.

Comment: Thanks! one outstanding question that I have is how to link desired page url with yii framework? For example I'd like to access "Terms" page via /terms path(I'll add path property into the Page model).

Comment: Change it in routing rules like `'/terms'=>'/site/page/view/terms'`.
You can have a separate file with routes and re-generate it on new page create/edit/delete.

Comment: is it possible to create a dynamic rules without routes file modification ?

Comment: As a quick solution: `'/~<page:\w+>'=>'/site/page/view/<page>'`